# Pandas remove space after regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, format

One of my columns currently has an extra space after a colon.

ex: `11-july-2011 11: 30:30`

Is there a way to remove the space without removing the first one as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can search for spaces which follow `:` and replace them:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace(':\s+', ':')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the Spaces using `.replace(':\s+', ':')` , this piece of code searches for a colon followed by a space and replaces it with a colon , so you basically just remove the space which is behind a colon :)

Answer (score 0):

different approach: you can parse to `datetime` - and `strftime` if you like, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.to_datetime("11-july-2011 11: 30:30", format='%d-%B-%Y %H: %M:%S')

t.isoformat()
# '2011-07-11T11:30:30'

t.strftime('%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S')
# 'July 11 2011, 11:30:30'
```